# Lego Creator - Ford Mustang 10265

Tags: sets, instructions

I open the box I purchased - the box had been opened prior - no instruction manual nor stickers - not a big deal, but how do I know how many bags I'm supposed to have in the box. I watched video and someone said 11 - but his numbers 22 were different. I have 1, 11, 2, 3, 33, 4, 44, 5, 6, 66 - am I missing 22 and 55?   In total I have 1-6 big bags, and 11, 33, 44, 66 little bags. Help please. I don't want to open each bag and count the parts individually

Answer (score 2):

There should indeed be 11 bags :

- 6 big ones numbered 1 through 6
- 5 small ones numbered 1, 2, 3, 4, 6 (each has the number on it multiple times, which seems to be why you mention 11, 33 etc.)
- the instructions and sticker sheet are in a protective plastic bag as well.

So, you appear to be missing small bag number 2.